# How Can I Host A WCF App In IIS?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I'm following Microsoft's tutorial on the topic here but it's not working and several items are unclear to me.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx

1. In step 2 it says, "ensure that ASP.NET has access to the contents of the folder".  How can i do this?
2. Is it correct that the .cs code not be compiled?  I've never ran .cs as a script of any kind.

Here is my error:

```
HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found
The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why is this remotely difficult?  This is a basic tutorial and it doesnt work, Microsoft!  come on.

Comment: Did you ensure that .Net framework 4.0 is properly installed?

Answer (score 14):

Could you please ensure that your apppool in which your site is running in "`Integrated`" mode rather than `Classic`.

If the problem is not resolved after doing this, try to register your IIS with .netv4.0

For doing that

Go to **Command Prompt**
Go to the location **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319**
Register the IIS using **aspnet_regiis -i** command

Comment: it is Integrated.  and running the cmd here didnt change the result.

Comment: can you try running ServiceModelReg.exe -i from the “%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation” directory to register the script maps and then try host the service?

Comment: Now i get this error:HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error
Handler "svc-Integrated" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list

Comment: can you try registering iis once again using the command aspnet_regiis.exe -i

Comment: Installing Asp.net helped solving me this issue.


Extract from Microsoft's link :
From a command prompt window, run the following command:
**\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\version\aspnet_regiis -i**

where version represents the version number of the .NET Framework installed on your computer, such as v1.0.370. You can determine the framework version by looking in the \WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework directory.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bztkys81.aspx

Comment: When `aspnet_regiis.exe -i` is not giving the results, `aspnet_regiis.exe -ir` may help instead (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wcftoolsteamblog/2010/04/02/common-setup-issues-and-their-resolutions-when-publishing-wcf-service-to-local-iis/)

Comment: it worked for me, despite I have already got this earlier (it was created by VS2017).

Answer (score 1):

1. Open IISManager and  go to handler mappings and right click on the static file and select "Revert to Parent"

Answer (score 0):

You can Host a WCF App/Service in IIS as you host simple website. It seems to me that you are trying to access/browse .cs file. If so, then it is not possible as it is code file. You should browse only your service file i.e. .svc file.

You can refer http://adarshdchaurasia.wordpress.com/2013/09/26/create-restful-wcf-service-api-using-get-post-step-by-step-guide/ to create a WCF service.

Please ensure that:

- You have .Net framework 4.0 installed and enabled on your machine. If
  not, install or try to re-install. Sometimes re-installation fix the
  unknown settings problem we accidentally create.
- First try to host a simple demo web site to check if the problem is
  with your WCF application or with hosting process your are
  following.

Comment: i am browsing to the .svc file as the tutorial mentions.

Comment: Did you verify if .Net version 4.0 is installed. Try "aspnet_regiis -i" command from visual studio 2010 command prompt. It will not cause any harm.

Comment: Put a html file in your WCF service application and check if that page is accessible. It will insure that there is not access related issue.

Comment: It seems that either you have .Net framework not installed properly or your WCF application has AppPool which is pointing to .Net version 3.5 or lower. Refer http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/280137/How-To-Deploy-a-Web-App-in-IIS. It explains how to verify if .Net is installed and appPool in pointing to v4.0

Answer (score 0):

> In step 2 it says, "ensure that ASP.NET has access to the contents of
>   the folder". How can i do this?

I think it mean make sure your folder are accessible by the `IIS_IUSRS`
Check the publish folder properties -> Security tab -> group or user name.

Make sure the app is using application pool with correct .net framework version.
normally I will just set .net framework v4.0.30319